# I'm stuck in AWS Lamba : Getting Started Guide

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Part 1.1 **Set Up an AWS Account and Create an Administrator User**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/setting-up.html

In the section for creating an IAM user, Step 3 is "Clear the check box next to Generate an access key for each user."

Part 1.2 **Set Up the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/setup-awscli.html

Step 2 says that the user created in Part 1.1 should be used to configure the AWS CLI.

AFAIK, the AWS CLI can only be configured with an Access Key ID & Secret, but the guide says this option should be cleared. Am I missing something, or is this just a typo in the guide?

Comment: if you are using AWS CLI in an EC2 Instance. You can assign a IAM role to the instance (While launching it) and access the particular resource using AWS CLI (No need of setting Access & Secret Keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the AWS CLI somewhere other than an EC2 server, then you are correct that you have to provide the Access Key and Secret Key. You will need to go back to the IAM console and create those keys.